# linux command : extracting lines from a tab delim. file whose first column containing a certain value

Tags: shell, cut

I have a tab deliminated txt file.

```
exon_id "ENSE00002234944"    exon_number "1"     gene_biotype "pseudogene"   gene_id   "ENSG00000223972"     gene_name "DDX11L1"
gene_biotype "pseudogene"    gene_id "ENSG00000223972"   gene_name "DDX11L1"     gene_source "ensembl_havana"    transcript_id "ENST00000456328"
exon_id "ENSE00002234632"    exon_number "1"     gene_biotype "pseudogene"   gene_id "ENSG00000223972"   gene_name "DDX11L1"
gene_biotype "pseudogene"    gene_id "ENSG00000223972"   gene_name "DDX11L1"     gene_source "ensembl_havana"    transcript_id "ENST00000515242"
exon_id "ENSE00002269724"    exon_number "1"     gene_biotype "pseudogene"   gene_id "ENSG00000223972"   gene_name "DDX11L1"
gene_biotype "pseudogene"    gene_id "ENSG00000223972"   gene_name "DDX11L1"     
gene_biotype "pseudogene"        gene_id "ENSG00000269732"       gene_name "WBP1LP7"         gene_source "havana"    transcript_id "ENST00000437905"
exon_id "ENSE00001687828"        exon_number "1"         gene_biotype "lincRNA"  gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"
gene_biotype "lincRNA"   gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"        gene_source "ensembl_havana"    transcript_id "ENST00000440163"
exon_id "ENSE00001628100"        exon_number "2"         gene_biotype "lincRNA"  gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"
exon_id "ENSE00001770724"        exon_number "3"         gene_biotype "lincRNA"  gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"
exon_id "ENSE00001622961"        exon_number "2"         gene_biotype "lincRNA"  gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"
exon_id "ENSE00002202695"        exon_number "2"         gene_biotype "pseudogene"          gene_id "ENSG00000256186"       gene_name "AL732372.1"
gene_biotype "pseudogene"        gene_id "ENSG00000256186"       gene_name "AL732372.1"    gene_source "ensembl"   transcript_id "ENST00000540477"
exon_id "ENSE00002305101"        exon_number "1"         gene_biotype "pseudogene"         gene_id "ENSG00000256186"       gene_name "AL732372.1"
exon_id "ENSE00001651491"        exon_number "1"         gene_biotype "lincRNA"  gene_id "ENSG00000237094"       gene_name "RP4-669L17.10"
```

As you can see, each line has 'gene_id' and 'gene_name' which I'm trying to extract, but the columns are not aligned. So I can't use "cut" to do it.

Actually, I can just use EXCEL to fill the empty fields to align and extract columns I want, but I think it is good to learn it for the future usages.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can grab the text starting from `gene_id` with `grep -o 'gene_id.*'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what awk was made for:

```
awk '$1 == "gene_biotype" {print $4, $6}' < input.txt
```

Explanation: $N represents a field, by default separated by whitespace. Any whitespace. The equality check says "Execute the rest of the line only when the first field matches gene_biotype". Then the appropriate fields are printed. If you want to remove the quotations, you can look at the `gsub` function, or you could be super lazy and pipe the output to `sed`.

Comment: It works! It seems to work only when the first field contains "gene_biotype". Anyhow, your answer fulfilled my needs, and I appreciate it again. Just curious, Can I command to read each line and extract a field contains "gene_id"?

Comment: If you tell us what you need, it should be easy.  Your question title mentions that you want to extract only when the first field contains a particular value, but you never told us what that value is, so this answer is necessarily speculative.

Comment: To get which field contains gene_id? I would use a loop from 1 to `NF`, which is the number of fields. If `$n == "gene_id"` then print `n` or `n+1` (the column number) or `$n` or `$n+1` (the actual field contents), depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better question would be, "how do I properly normalize this data".  Your tagged field format is not a good fit for TSV (it should be tab-separated *values* only; the keys are the column indices).  You should probably translate this into a format which is aligned with the requirements of the tools you want to use.

A comma-separated or tab-separated file makes sense when the set of keys is static, the values are simple, unstructured text or numbers, and most of the values are populated most of the time.

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS
 f="exon_id:exon_number:gene_biotype:gene_id:gene_name:gene_source:transcript_id"
   n=split(f, field, /:/); for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) key[field[i]]=i }
 { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        split($i, v, / /); gsub(/^"|"$/, "", v[2]); value[key[v[1]]]=v[2] }
    s=""; for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) { printf("%s%s", s, value[i]); s="\t" };
      printf "\n"; delete value }' data.txt >data.new
```

This normalizes it so that the first field always contains `exon_id` and the `gene_id` is always in column four, etc (the `f` value on the second line defines the field order).  The field names are no longer in the data because they are already implied by the data's position in the file.  Now, extracting the data you want should hopefully be trivial.

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 == "pseudogene" { print $4, $5 }' data.new
```

Sometimes, CSV/TSV has the column titles on the first line of the file, but this is a hassle for automated processing.  You should document the field to column index mapping once and for all in one place.

Alternatively, if the data is somewhat more sparsely populated than your example suggests, or if you want the freedom to add or remove some fields from time to time, and/or if some values have an internal structure, perhaps a structured format is a better fit.  Your sample is trivial to transform into [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

```
awk '{ printf (NR==1 ? "[" : ",\n");
    printf "{"; s="";
    for (i=1; i<NF; i +=2) { printf ("%s\"%s\": %s", s, $i, $(i+1)); s=", " }
    printf "}"; }
  END { printf "]\n" }' data.txt >data.json
```

There are alternatives such as YAML and XML, but JSON is simple, flexible, and well-supported (and XML would seem like severe overkill here).  Now, you can refer to properties by their name, instead of the column number:

```
 jq '.[] | select(.gene_biotype == "pseudogene") |
    { gene_id, gene_name }' data.json
```

The [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool in particular is fine with JSONs format (a [stream of JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Streaming) fragments) so the Awk script can be simplified even further if you commit to a JSONs toolchain rather than a general JSON toolchain.  This will somewhat restrict your choice of tools, but if your needs are simple, maybe that's okay (and anyway, a sequence of JSON fragments of identical structure can easily be wrapped with `[..., ..., ...]` into proper JSON format).

```
awk '{ printf "{"; s="";
    for (i=1; i<NF; i +=2) { printf ("%s\"%s\": %s", s, $i, $(i+1)); s=", " }
    printf "}"; }' data.txt >data.jsons
```

Then you can extract with just

```
 jq 'select(.gene_biotype == "pseudogene") |
    { gene_id, gene_name }' data.jsons
```

If you want another field than "gene_biotype" with a value of "pseudogene", please update your question to indicate under what conditions you want to extract a value; or to extract unconditionally, just remove the `select(...)` condition, or the `$3 == "..."` in the Awk code.